# Detect when object values, that match, all have a new prop and fire a method from it

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this below which represents a carousel and it's slides:

```
[
  {
    text: "Lorem",
    imgSrc: "Url",
    section: "t1"
  },
  {
    text: "Lorem",
    imgSrc: "Url",
    section: "t1"
  },
  {
    text: "Lorem",
    imgSrc: "Url",
    section: "t2"
  },
  {
    text: "Lorem",
    imgSrc: "Url",
    section: "t2"
  },
  {
    text: "Lorem",
    imgSrc: "Url",
    section: "t3"
  }
]
```

And when a slide is viewed, I'm adding a prop `viewed: true` to that particular object, i.e:

```
{
  text: "Lorem",
  imgSrc: "Url",
  section: "t2",
  viewed: true
}
```

This is the method that fires when a carousel slide has been viewed and sets the viewed prop:

```
onSlideViewed() {
  _.map(this.tutorialSlides, (slide, index) => {
    if (currentIndex === Number(index)) {
      slide.viewed = true;
    }
  });
}
```

I want to be able to detect when a whole section (all "t2" for example) has been viewed and fire a method when it does but I'm struggling to be figure out how to set the loop up that check that all sections have been viewed - can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all… `this.tutorialSlides[currentIndex].viewed = true`…?! Secondly: `this.tutorialSlides.every(slide => slide.viewed)`…!?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I understand your first part of the comment but the second not so much. I am still needing help to see when all slides in one section has been viewed, can you help with that?

Comment: The above `every` expression will tell you whether all slides have been viewed. E.g. `if (this...every(...))`. Just put that at the end of your `onSlideViewed` function?

Comment: I am getting .every is not a function. I understand what you are saying but how can I detect that the two objects that have `section: "t1"` have both got the viewed property? Not all, just the section

Comment: 1) See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for `every`, look at the browser compatibility chart, and perhaps at the polyfill. 2) If you want to do this for a specific section only, combine it with `filter`: `this.tutorialSlides.filter(slide => slide.section == 't1').every(...)`. If this still doesn't help, update your question to eliminate details that have already been solved and concentrate on the remaining issue(s).